# why there is no speed difference between Python's map function and for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a pandas DataFrame, `data`, with column, `short_description` containing texts. I am doing some preprocessing on each row. I tried for loop to go through each row and do all the preprocessing steps one by one and then save the results into a list.

This is slow for me as I have more than 800000 rows. I tried python's `map()` function, but there is still no speed boost. 
I tried with 20000 rows and I see almost the same speed difference between map and for loop.

Following are my ways of performing preprocessing:
`data`

```
# FOR loop
final_output = []
for i in range(0, len(data['short_description'].values)):
    document = data['short_description'].values[i]
    document = document.encode('utf-8')
    document = re.sub(r'\.com', '', document)
    document = document.translate(string.maketrans(string.punctuation,' '*len(string.punctuation)))
    document = document.replace('“', ' ')
    document = document.replace('”', ' ')
    document = document.replace('’', ' ')
    document = document.split()
    document = [lemmer.lemmatize(token) for token in document]
    document = [snowstemmer.stem(wert) for wert in document]
    document_ngrams = list(everygrams(document, 2,4))
    document_ngrams = [' '.join(document_ngrams[gram_index]) for gram_index in range(0, len(document_ngrams))]
    final_output.append(document_ngrams)
```

```
def preprocess_steps(df_column):
    document = df_column.encode('utf-8')
    document = re.sub(r'\.com', '', document)
    document = document.translate(string.maketrans(string.punctuation,' '*len(string.punctuation)))
    document = document.replace('“', ' ')
    document = document.replace('”', ' ')
    document = document.replace('’', ' ')
    document = document.split() #tokenization
    document = list(filter(lambda token: lemmer.lemmatize(token), document))
    document = list(filter(lambda wert: snowstemmer.stem(wert), document))
    document_ngrams = list(everygrams(document, 2,4))
    document_ngrams = list(map(lambda x : ' '.join(x), document_ngrams))
    return document_ngrams

final_output=list(map(preprocess_steps, data['short_description']))
```

Why there is no speed boost with `map()` function? Any suggestions? 
**Why I think there should be a speed difference**
Because I read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-vs-for-loop/).
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think there would be?

Comment: You have conflicting statements in your question. You ask why there is no speed difference, and then you say that one is slower than the other. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: I read map functions work in parallel?

Comment: You seem to confuse this with [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

Comment: [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-vs-for-loop/) is an example showing speed difference between the two.

Comment: That's such a small example that sampling errors and setup code will dominate anything. You might want to look at multiprocessing's `map` for running maps in parallel instead: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map -- And when optimizing anything, start with the output from your profiler, then work from that (you're using regex for something a simple replace might do, etc.)

Comment: That example is flawed, the `for` loop variant uses `print` in each iteration.

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you for some useful pointer.

Comment: If I may suggest your calling ."document.replace()" function multiple times why don't you try iterating document (for loop) once char by char and compare them for special chars you might want to replace using some condition. By this way I'm sure you will observe some performance difference.This way instead of 3 times iteration you will do single.

Comment: The processing that you are doing with each item is so heavy that the overhead of the loop becomes negligible. For a test, you could remove all the processing and just returning the unchanged item.

Answer (score -2):

Map is faster than the list comprehension which itself is faster than the classic for loop. Take a look at the following example:

```
import time
ml = list(range(100000))

tic = time.time()
el = []
for i in ml:
    el.append(i*7)
toc = time.time()
print(toc-tic) # 0.0223 s

tic = time.time()
el = [i*7 for i in ml]
toc = time.time()
print(toc-tic) # 0.0069 s

tic = time.time()
el = map(lambda x: x*7, ml)
toc = time.time()
print(toc-tic) # 0.0009 s
```

Comment: `map` only creates a "lazy" iterable while other two are doing computations, that's why you see that difference in timings (which are inaccurate, please use `timeit` module instead)